# lualatex doesn't run when under www-data

Tags: luatex

we are using `lualatex` to produce some automatically generated documents on our webserver.

We do have an Ubuntu 18.04 based server, on which Nginx runs as webserver.  Nginx does not run as `root`, but as a different user `www-data`.  On some websites, there is a script, which generates a LaTeX file.  This LaTeX files compiles without error, if it is called manually as user `root` with `lualatex filename.tex`.  Therefore I daresay, that all needed classes, styles and such are available.

If the same file is run as user `www-data`, using the same identical command, it stops nearly immediately after loading the LaTeX input file and calling LaTeX2e.

Ironically, `lualatex` sends a return value of `0`, i.e. no error.  There is only a log file generated, which is 12 lines long.  Even the log file does not contain any errors or further hints, why `lualatex` did not succeed. This is the said log-file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2019.3.12)  12 MAR 2019 16:53
 restricted system commands enabled.
**04-201901.tex
(./04-201901.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-02-14 2.64 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-02-14 2.64 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / logging
```

Does anybody have any hints, what to do, to get `lualatex` running in this webserver (with restricted rights as user `www-data`)?

Comment: I don't use lualatex that much, but doesn't it need somewhere to write the otfload cache to? I don't think www-data has a home dir. Have you checked if there are any options to where to place the cache. Note that root **does** have a home dir

Comment: Relevant information: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/issues/450

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by daleif, luaotfload fails to find a suitable directory for it's caches because there is no writable texmf-var directory in the user directory of `ẁww-data`.
But you can help `lualatex`: Instead of running

```
lualatex <your options> filename.tex
```

you can use

```
TEXMFCACHE=:/tmp/ lualatex <your options> filename.tex
```

where `/tmp` can be any directory the user `www-data` can write to.

As suggested by Ulrike Fischer in the chat, this might only be an indicator for a bigger problem: You really should add some writable path to `TEXMFVAR`. So a better fix would be to create some directory (I will use `/some/dir/for/www-data`), for which `www-data` has write permissions and then set the environment variable `TEXMFVAR` to `/some/dir/for/www-data:` before executing `lualatex`. How to do this depends on your specific invocation of `lualatex` because `www-data` probably does not even has a shell.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you very much!